# Clipit Hotkeys Stop Working Whenever System Goes into Powersavig Mode

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, clipboard-manager

In Ubuntu 18.04, the hotkeys in Clipit (e.g., Cntl-Alt-H for History) stop working after the system goes into Powersaving mode (and maybe stop working at other times, too).

If I then go into ClipIt's Preferences and re-accept the Hotkey layouts, they start working again.

I love ClipIt and would like to be able to have the Hotkeys persist. Any ideas how to do this or what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and just thought about asking a question here before I saw that you already asked about this. The problem occurs also when the screen is locked, and it also results in the current text being removed from the clipboard. The quickest way to reenable the hotkeys is to go to the preferences and simply click OK.

Comment: Yes, @Stefan, that's exactly what I do to fix it. Not hard, but not having to do that would be easier.